# convert Authorize Attirbute to VB for Web API

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

sorry for the really dumb question but I'm not real great with VB. I'm trying to add an Authorize attribute to my web api controller.  In C# it would be

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
```

but I can't for the life of me get it converted into VB.
tried

```
 <Authorize(New Roles({"admin"}))>
```

but not so much.

Comment: yes sorry this is a duplicate of that question can I close this one? or should I just mark the one below as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You just use wrong syntax it will be:

```
<Authorize(Roles := "admin")> _
```